# pandas set_axis both index and column axes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to set both axes of a pandas DataFrame?  I am currently using a utility function that calls `set_axis` on both axes:

```
def DataFrame_set_axes(df, index, columns):
    """Set both the index and column axes of DataFrame."""
    return df.set_axis(index, axis='index').set_axis(columns, axis='columns')
```

But this does not seem like the best solution.  I am looking for something that can be called simply like: `df.set_axes(index, columns)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values, index=index, columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign the new indices/columns to the `index`/`columns` attributes:

```py
df.index, df.columns = index, columns
```